# (Excel) How to return column header of the nth highest values with formula

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, rank

Given a table like this one below:

|  | David | Mike | Lisa |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| David | 50 | 10 | 40 |
| Mike | 0 | 50 | 50 |
| Lisa | 10 | 40 | 50 |

I'm trying to come up with a column of formulas and information that will automatically rank and label.  See below for a correct output example.

| Chosen Row -> | Mike (this cell is defined by the user) |
| --- | --- |
| **Rank** | **Number** |
| Mike | 50 |
| Lisa | 50 |
| David | 0 |

Basically the user should be able to change the top right cell and have the rest of the table automatically adjust based on that input.

Here, the user input "Mike" into the cell, so the formulas should look into the row labeled "Mike" (with the values 0, 50, and 50 in that order) and tell me a list of the highest scoring column names, along with their scores.

The only thing that is tripping me up is integrating something into the formula that makes it skip names it has already put into the rank list.  As you can see, there are 2 scores of 50 there.

There is a page for this on Microsofts website on dealing with ties, but I don't fully grasp their example where they use Countif, so I have not been able to translate it over for my purposes.  They also use rank numbers to the left of the names in their example, but I'd prefer that not be necessary if possible.  I don't mind writing the cell formulas by hand if auto-fill doesn't help me with certain aspects.

I know there is a way to accomplish this.  I've played with the formulas and did a lot of research.  I've just about resorted to coding it all in VBA, but I feel like that would be far more work.  At this point I'm so close, I feel like I'm just missing one critical element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one has the dynamic formula in Office 365 then we can use SORT:

```
=SORT(CHOOSE({1,2},TRANSPOSE(B1:D1),TRANSPOSE(INDEX(B2:D4,MATCH(H1,A2:A4,0),0))),2,-1)
```

And Excel will spill the results correctly.

[image]

---

For older we need two formula:

First get the values in order:

```
=LARGE(INDEX($B$2:$D$4,MATCH($H$1,$A$2:$A$4,0),0),ROW(ZZ1))
```

Put that in H2 and copy down.

Then we need to reference those value to get the correct name:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,AGGREGATE(15,7,(COLUMN(INDEX($B$2:$D$4,MATCH($H$1,$A$2:$A$4,0),0))-MIN(COLUMN(INDEX($B$2:$D$4,MATCH($H$1,$A$2:$A$4,0),0)))+1)/(INDEX($B$2:$D$4,MATCH($H$1,$A$2:$A$4,0),0)=H2),COUNTIF($H$2:H2,H2)))
```

Put that in G2 and copy down.

[image]

Comment: I've tried doing this but apparently my version of Excel either doesn't support "sort" or I need to do something to enable it.  I have 365 ProPlus

Comment: If you have O365 it should have sort.  what is the response?

Comment: when i hit enter, it just highlights the word sort and wont' let me leave the cell.

Comment: I may be lost in translation (AGAIN) with these column/row seperators for en-us, but....`=SORT(TRANSPOSE(CHOOSE({1,2},B1:D1,FILTER(B2:D4,A2:A4=H1))),2,-1)` might be another m365 alternative (not worth a seperate answer).

Comment: @JvdV I am too anchored on INDEX/MATCH.  Yes FILTER is an excellent alternative.

Comment: I was thinking that in this case maybe even `=SORT(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B1:D4,(A1:A4=H1)+(A1:A4=""))),2,-1)` would do. Maybe too dependent on the empty cell of `A1`.

Comment: So that worked for Mike but if I change the user input cell to "David" it errors out the 2 other ranks.

Comment: I am not getting that issue: https://imgur.com/jxLB9bT @John  make sure the ranges align to the data and are absolute($) where needed.

Comment: I copied your exact formula to cell G2, and auto filled it to G4.  Not sure if manual editing was required but the only change that occurred was at the end.  The first one ends in =H2),COUNTIF($H$2:H2,H2))) and the second one ends in =H3),COUNTIF($H$2:H3,H3)))

Comment: show a picture of the sheet with the errors and G2 selected so I can see the formula.

Comment: The issue is not the formula in the selected cell but the one that is returning the numbers to the right.  Did you put the other formula in those cells so they change when the person changes? `=LARGE(INDEX($B$2:$D$4,MATCH($H$1,$A$2:$A$4,0),0),ROW(ZZ1))` should have been put in H2 and copied down. @John

Comment: Oh no I guess I didn't.  Duh.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I made in excel 2016, but I think it works in all versions. First I created a Rank, then I used the Index function. Download the file here:

https://1drv.ms/x/s!Apn_2zN0NfqFhWT-OdNazVTlxI2n?e=WsZLuH

Code for Rank using array formula:

```
=MATCH(LARGE(INDIRECT("B"&$K$1&":D"&$K$1)+COLUMN(INDIRECT("B"&$K$1&":D"&$K$1))/100000,ROW()-2),
INDIRECT("B"&$K$1&":D"&$K$1)+COLUMN(INDIRECT("B"&$K$1&":D"&$K$1))/100000,0)
```

[image]